# Merge two list of tuples with unequal length

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can one merge two unequal list of tuples:

```
x = [('Animal', 1), ('Bird', 2)]
y = [('Animal', 'Dog'), ('Animal', 'Cat'), ('Bird', 'Parrot')]
```

..to get..

```
[('Animal', 1, 'Dog'), ('Animal', 1, 'Cat'), ('Bird', 2, 'Parrot')]
```

..using list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn `x` into a dictionary for easier searching, then...

```
xx = dict(x)
[(k, xx[k], a) for k, a in y]
# => [('Animal', 1, 'Dog'), ('Animal', 1, 'Cat'), ('Bird', 2, 'Parrot')]
```

EDIT: That's quite a different question now.

```
[(k, n, a) for k, a in y for kk, n in x if kk == k]
# => [('Animal', 1, 'Dog'), ('Animal', 2, 'Dog'), ('Animal', 1, 'Cat'),
#     ('Animal', 2, 'Cat'), ('Bird', 2, 'Parrot')]
```

You can again speed it up by transforming `x` into a dictionary of animals to lists of numbers.

Comment: What if x has duplicate values in the key i.e. 'x = [('Animal', 1), ('Animal', 2), ('Bird', 2)]' to get an expected output of **[('Animal', 1, 'Dog'), ('Animal', 1, 'Cat'), ('Animal', 2, 'Dog'), ...]**

Comment: `[(k, n, a) for k, a in y for kk, a in x if kk = k]` gives invalid syntax error in `if kk = k`

Comment: `[(k, n, a) for k, a in y for kk, n in x if kk == k]` --- works well! Thx